# Renaming files in MATLAB

Tags: file, string, matlab

I'm trying to programmatically rename a file in the working directory from `a = 'temp.txt'` to `b = 'hello.txt'`. How would you suggest doing so? Is there an easy file renaming function in MATLAB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for MOVEFILE.

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a list of a few solutions:

- Use the [MOVEFILE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/movefile.html) function (as suggested by [mtrw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275099/renaming-files-in-matlab/1275373#1275373)).
- Use the [SYSTEM](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/system.html) function to execute an operating system command. For example (on Windows):

  ```
  system('rename temp.txt hello.txt');
  system(['rename ' a ' ' b]);  % If the file names are stored in strings
  ```
- Use the [shell escape operator](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-41244.html#f0-45836) (`!`) to invoke a system command. For example (on Windows):

  ```
  !rename temp.txt hello.txt
  ```

  If the file names are stored in strings, you would need to use [EVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html):

  ```
  a = 'temp.txt';
  b = 'hello.txt';
  eval(['!rename ' a ' ' b]);
  ```