# Matlab publish - Want to use a custom file name to publish several pdf files

Tags: matlab, pdf, rename, publish

I have several data log files (here: 34) for those I have to calculate some certain values. I wrote a seperate function to publish the results of the calculation in a pdf file. But I only can publish one file after another, so it takes a while to publish all 34 files.

Now I want to automize that with a loop - importing the data, calculate the values and publish the results for every log file in a new pdf file. I want 34 pdf files for every log file at the end.

**My problem is, that I couldn't find a way to rename the pdf files during publishing. The pdf file is always named after the script which is calculating the values. Obviously the pdf is overwritten within a loop. So at the end everything is calculated, but I only have the pdf from the last calculated log file.**

---

There was this hacky solution to change the Matlab publish script, but since I don't have admin rights I can't use that:

*"This is really hacky, but I would modify publish to accept a new option prefix. Replace line 93*

```
[scriptDir,prefix] = fileparts(fullPathToScript);
```

*with*

```
if ~isfield(options, 'prefix')
    [scriptDir,prefix] = fileparts(fullPathToScript); 
else
    [scriptDir,~] = fileparts(fullPathToScript);
    prefix = options.prefix; end
```

*Now you can set options.prefix to whatever filename you want. If you want to be really hardcore, make the appropriate modifications to supplyDefaultOptions and checkOptionFields as well."*

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: Rather than show the code that you can't use, it might be helpful to show the code where you loop and call the publish function so we can work with what you have.

Comment: there was no use for the source code, because it was a logical problem. it was easier to explain what I wanted to do. thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one idea using [`movefile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movefile.html) to rename the resultant published PDF on each iteration:

```
for i = 1:34
    file = publish(files(i)); % Replace with your own command(s)
    [pathStr,fileName,ext] = fileparts(file);
    newFile = [pathStr filesep() fileName '_' int2str(i) ext]; % Example: append _# to each
    [success,msg,msgid] = movefile(file,newFile);
    if ~success
        error(msgid,msg);
    end
end
```

Also used are [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) and [`filesep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filesep.html). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275099/renaming-files-in-matlab) for other ways to rename and move files.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response. It worked with 'movefile' within a loop. So the everytime a pdf file was created it was renamed immediatly before the values from next file were calculated.